# How to remove breadcrumb from homepage in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using Enigma theme in wordpress and i want to remove breadcrumb only from homepage. please tell me how to remove it.Below is my breadcrumb code in functions.php

```
<?php
if (is_page() && $post->post_parent) {
    $parent_id = $post->post_parent;
    $breadcrumbs = array();
    while ($parent_id) {
        $page = get_page($parent_id);
        $breadcrumbs[] = '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . get_the_title($page->ID) . '</a></li>';
        $parent_id = $page->post_parent;
    }
    $breadcrumbs = array_reverse($breadcrumbs);
    foreach ($breadcrumbs as $crumb)
        echo $crumb . ' ' . $delimiter . ' ';
    echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
}
?>
```

Comment: Please provide more information, also show us what you have tried already ?

Comment: I am trying to remove it from its engime-theme.css by display:none; but its not working...can't understand how to remove it

Comment: Please put some code and some html so we can help you, no one will go to install Enigma theme for you.

Comment: i have put my code above now give any solution Mr. @Milap

Comment: I seen demo here : https://wordpress.org/themes/enigma/ I did not see any bredcrumb on home page.

Comment: But after customize this theme it shows breadcrumb in all pages included home page.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109117/wordpress-professional-help Join this, maybe someone will help you.

Comment: @Milap not able to chat coz i dont have 20 reputation :(

Comment: Oh i see, try to earn some reputation then :)

Comment: Sure :) @ Milap thnx for ur help....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove breadcrumb from home page only then add the following code into the functions.php of your theme/child theme directory.

```
if ( is_home() ) {
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 10, 0);
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Try this : add_filter( 'breadcrumb_trail', '__return_false' ); in functions.php

Answer (score 0):

- Create a child-theme
- remove the line of code from the file Page.php save file

  ```
    "get_template_part('breadcrums');"
  ```

  This will remove the breadcrumbs from your Pages (in child theme only)

  Similarly , Do this for single.php

  or

/wp-content/themes/enigma/css/enigma-theme.css

change this:

```
.breadcrumb li {
  display: inline-block;
  }

 to this:

.breadcrumb li {
    display: none;
  }
```